# Giving cat output to rm

Tags: command-line, bash, rm, cat

I have file names in a file which I need to delete in a different directory.

Let's say I have `x` and `y` files in dir `a`. How do I delete it using cat?

I tried,

```
rm -f a/{`cat a.txt`}
```

`a.txt` has contents `x,y,z`.

If they are in the same folder, I can put `x y z` in `a.txt` and run,

```
rm -f `cat a.txt`
```

which works fine.

I have also tried,

```
rm -f "a/{"`cat a.txt`"}"
```

This command will go in a dockerfile so I prefer not to use any variables too.

I ***do not*** want to put `a/x a/y a/z` in the file which can be an option, as it is fixed that `a` will only contain the files. But `a` should be changed only in the dockerfile. Thanks for all suggestions in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your filenames don't contain spaces or any special characters, just reuse your original command with a `cd` before it:

```
(cd a; rm -f $(cat a.txt))
```

Be warned that `` rm -f `cat a.txt` `` breaks easily with spaces or any special characters in filenames, you should really use `xargs` with NUL-delimited filenames.

Comment: This would work. Though `cd` doesn't look like the best way to go. It still is better than all other options. Thanks :).

Answer (score 2):

You should use while loop to read file line by line and then apply each line to `rm`. This a very common and frequently used approach in scripting

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
       rm a/"$line"
done < file.txt
```

Naturally the format of the file should be list of files with one file per line

Comment: Yes, this could work, but I would avoid `while`. Thanks :)

Comment: @OptimusPrime You're welcome. Mind if I ask why you want to avoid `while` loop ?

Comment: Just a preference :) A single line command looks much better and easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to use `$(cat file)` for this kind of thing - it will break for example if there are spaces in file names e.g. given

```
$ cat a.txt 
foo
bar baz
bam
```

and

```
$ ls -Q a
"bam"  "bar baz"  "foo"  "other file"  "somefile"
```

then

```
$ (cd a ; rm $(cat ../a.txt))
rm: cannot remove 'bar': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'baz': No such file or directory
```

Instead, you can use `xargs`

```
$ ls -Q a
"bam"  "bar baz"  "foo"  "other file"  "somefile"
$ xargs -a a.txt -I{} rm a/{}
$ ls -Q a
"other file"  "somefile"
```

If you *really* want to use `cat`, then combine it with `xargs`:

```
cat a.txt | xargs -I{} rm a/{}
```

(although given the `-a` feature, it's a [Useless Use of Cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html))

---

Note that `-I{}` implies `-L 1` i.e. `rm` is invoked once for each line of the input file; if you don't need to prepend a directory path, then you can make the command more efficient by doing away with the `-I` in which case `xargs` will pass multiple arguments to `rm`. However in that case you should explicitly set the input delimiter to newline e.g. `xargs -a a.txt -d '\n' rm` to prevent breaking on spaces.